# Is this how a minheap is sorted?

Tags: java

My professor claims my Minheap is incorrect on the following question:

Convert the following numbers to **minheap** using **min heap down** and draw the final minheap tree level by level and final array content.

Array given: 100   10    80    30    60    50    40    70    20    90

My answer was as follows:

```
                     10
                /          \
             20             40
            /  \           /  \
          30    60       80    50
          /\    /
        100 70  90
```

Sorted Array: 10,20,40,30,60,80,50,100,70,90

*Am I incorrect?*

Answer (score 2):

A Min-Heap is a complete binary tree in which the value in each internal node is smaller than or equal to the values in the children of that node.
Mapping the elements of a heap into an array is trivial: if a node is stored an index k, then its left child is stored at index 2k + 1 and its right child at index 2k + 2.

your answer is right you miss placed 70 and 100 that's wrong here otherwise its correct

the sorted array will be

> 10,20,40,30,60,50,80,70,100,90